# In clang, why does this template default parameter require the destructor to be instantiated?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
struct incomplete_type;

#if 0
struct incomplete_type {
    static void foo() {}
};
#endif

template<typename T>
struct problem_type
{
    constexpr problem_type(int) noexcept {};
    constexpr problem_type(double) noexcept : problem_type(5) {}

    ~problem_type() {
        T::foo();
    }
};

void bar(problem_type<incomplete_type> arg=5.0) noexcept;
```

When `bar` has a default parameter which calls a forwarding constructor which is also `constexpr`, the compiler also attempts to instantiate the destructor, which fails, because `T::foo` cannot be called because `T` is an incomplete type.

The problem does not occur if the default parameter does not invoke a forwarding constructor (e.g. if we change `5.0` to `5`), if the forwarding constructor is not `constexpr`, or (of course) if the type `T` is complete at this point.

The problem does also occur if the destructor is `constexpr`, even if the constructor is not forwarding.

`noexcept` appears to be irrelevant, but I have left it in to ensure the compiler is not attempting to generate stack unwinding code.

This only occurs on clang (12.0.1), not on gcc (11.2) or Visual Studio (19.29). See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/88b3eW8q7)

Note that the function `bar` *is not defined or called*.

**Why does this not compile in clang?**

Comment: Sounds like a bug, default arguments are evaluated in the context of the caller. Possibly related: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42303

Comment: Seems like as part of instantiating the class template, possibly allowed by [\[temp.inst\]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp#inst-11), it's attempting to determine whether or not `problem_type(double)` is in fact `constexpr` for that specialization.

Answer (score 3):

This is a compiler bug, namely it seems to be [LLVM issue 41648 / bug 42303](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/41648).

Default arguments like `= 5` should not result in instantiation of any class members, because [[dcl.fct.default] p5](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default#5) explains that only semantic constraints are checked, and the actual evaluation takes place as if you copy-initialized `arg` to `5.0` at the call site.

Furthermore:

> Unless a member of a templated class is a declared specialization, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist or if the existence of the definition of the member affects the semantics of the program; [...]

- [[temp.inst] p4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#4)

The destructor `~problem_type` is a member, and the existence of the default argument `5` should not be invoking the destructor (that should happen at the call site of `bar`), thus

- its not referenced in a context that requires its definition to exist, and
- the existence of its definition does not affect the semantics of the program.

This means clang is prematurely instantiating the destructor when it shouldn't be.