# Did the rules for nullptr init of unique_ptr change in C++23?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer, unique-ptr, c++23

This code compiles with MSVC from VS 2022 in C++20 mode. It failes in C++23 mode. (`/std:c++latest`)

```
#include <memory>

struct A;

struct B {
    B();
    ~B();

    std::unique_ptr<A> ptr{nullptr};
};

int main(){
    B b;
}
```

Current versions of GCC and clang accept this code in C++23 mode.

[Live Code on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bKaYG3hqG)

MSVC in C++23 mode:

```
C:/data/msvc/14.38.33133/include\memory(3169): error C2027: use of undefined type 'A'
<source>(3): note: see declaration of 'A'
C:/data/msvc/14.38.33133/include\memory(3169): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
<source>(9): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<A,std::default_delete<A>>' being compiled
C:/data/msvc/14.38.33133/include\memory(3205): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::default_delete<A>' being compiled
C:/data/msvc/14.38.33133/include\memory(3168): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::default_delete<A>::operator ()(_Ty *) noexcept const'
        with
        [
            _Ty=A
        ]
C:/data/msvc/14.38.33133/include\memory(3280): note: see the first reference to 'std::default_delete<A>::operator ()' in 'std::unique_ptr<A,std::default_delete<A>>::~unique_ptr'
C:/data/msvc/14.38.33133/include\memory(3169): error C2338: static_assert failed: 'can't delete an incomplete type'
C:/data/msvc/14.38.33133/include\memory(3170): warning C4150: deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'A'; no destructor called
<source>(3): note: see declaration of 'A'
```

Microsoft [answerd me](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/10514504) (not public available yet) that the new behavior is due to `constexpr std::unique_ptr` in C++23 mode and they are just following the standard with this.

Is this corrent? Are GCC and clang are wrong to accept this code in C++23 mode?

---

I'll add some more explanation to what happens here, because some of the comments indicate that this is not obvious.

The constructor of `std::unique_ptr<A>` is called here. It doesn't call the constructor of the incomplete type `A`, because it is initialized with a `nullptr`. This part seams to be fine for MSVC in C++23 mode.

The **destructor** of `std::unique_ptr<A>` is **not called** here. It is called from the destructor of `B` which is defined in another source code file, where `A` is a complete type. This works with GCC and clang. It also works with MSVC in C++20 mode. In C++23 mode MSVC complains, that it can not instantiate the destructor of `std::unique_ptr<A>` because `A` is not a complete type here.

In my opinion the destructor should never be instantiated from this code unit.

The MSVC support on the other hand told me, that this is valid for C++23, because `std::unique_ptr` is now `constexpr`.

Comment: Using incomplete type is undefined behavior?

Comment: See [Why is the complete type required?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25850680/12002570) and why it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Also see [why does c++ unique_ptr with incomplete types compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71686814/why-does-c-unique-ptr-with-incomplete-types-compile)

Comment: An incomplete type seems to be partially supported : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr : *std::unique_ptr may be constructed for an incomplete type T*, but it must be complete by the time the destructor is called.

Comment: So when you make A complete type before main, there is no problem : https://godbolt.org/z/Tzj14fPEK

Comment: I dare say it's a bug in msvc. The default c'tor and the c'tor taking a nullptr_t have the same semantics + requirements. Removing the explicit initializer makes msvc perfectly happy, even though the meaning of the program shouldn't change.

Comment: The linked "duplicates" are not answering if there was a behavior change between C++20 and C++23. The destructor of ptr is called from ~B which is defined in another file where A is complete. Why does MSVC complain about that when it is not called from this code unit?

Comment: The [c++23 constexpr change](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) was to the c'tor accepting a pointer (not nullptr_t). If msvc collapse the two into one, that would be nonconforming and would explain the misbhavior.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica In this case can you please reopen this question and post this as an answer? Microsoft told me explicitly, that they think this is not a bug. I wanted some prove that they are wrong or that they are correct. The linked dups are not answering my question.

Comment: I don't know that Microsoft are wrong, only suspect possible bugs. AFAIK nothing changes that should make the code ill-formed since the time the other posts were asked. But I re-opened since your focus is much narrower than the other posts.

Comment: If the code you show is the code causing the problem now, it was never correct according to the standard since A is NOT complete in main (at least that's how I understand it). And I would say the previous compiler versions where incorrect in accepting it.  And the only thing that changed is that C++23 is complying with the standard better. (This happens often when compilers get updated). Or do I miss something

Comment: @PepijnKramer - It was always correct, what are you on? Incomplete types were allowed so long as they were completed before needing to be complete

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The thing is in the code example A never becomes a complete type, it is only there has a forward declaration. So when B gets destructured, std::unique_ptr needs A to be a complete type.

Comment: @PepijnKramer - It becomes complete in another TU. `main.cpp` is never linked.

Comment: *"If msvc collapse the two into one, that would be nonconforming and would explain the misbhavior."* - Actually, I think I'm wrong here. Even if they are collapsed, it won't explain the behavior (and could theoretically work under the as-if rule). Still, the default c'tor and the nullptr_t c'tor should behave exactly the same, so the difference is still non-conforming and is a bug on its own.

Comment: There was no need to reopen the question. The exact [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71686814/why-does-c-unique-ptr-with-incomplete-types-compile).

Comment: @user12002570 No it is not. The code is the same, but the question is another ...

Comment: Answer posted here can be used there also. So this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Alan These answers not even refer to C++23 and constexpr unique_ptr. (Which is the main point of this question.)

Comment: @BenjaminBuch I know that but any answer posted here can be posted in the duplicates. That is, they(the answers here) are applicable to them(the duplicate posts) also

Comment: Instantiating `std::default_delete<A>` by itself doesn't instantiate the definitions of member functions. MSVC seems to be instantiating the definition of `std::default_delete<A>::operator()` when it shouldn't, which caused the `static_assert` to fire.

Comment: @Alan My question is about a possible bug in the MSVC compiler or in both GCC and clang for C++23. Which one is right must be proven by the C++ standard. The dup questions are refering to older C++ standards. These are different standards, you can not prove this question about the currend standard by an old one.

Comment: @Alan I believe the dupes all define ctor+dtor while the element type is still incomplete, while this one doesn't.

Comment: The discussion on the bug report seems to reveal a possible trigger cause, namely, that the destructor of `unique_ptr` being constexpr in 23 causes it to get instantiated eagerly as soon as it's named by any potentially-evaluated expression. But I'm still not seeing any good reason why it should be named in the first place. Probably a compiler bug.

Comment: Some related questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69118310/in-clang-why-does-this-template-default-parameter-require-the-destructor-to-be), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68870677/must-destructor-be-just-available-public-or-fully-valid-for-default-initialize)

Answer (score 2):

I have spent some time researching the question over the last few days and I think I can now give the answer myself.

**No, the rules didn't change.**

It is a compiler bug in MSVC that was not noticed before because `unique_ptr` was not `constexpr`. GCC and clang have different but releated bugs.

The essential rules are as follows:

[temp.inst-11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/temp.spec#temp.inst-11)

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member class or static data member of a templated class, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement ([stmt.if]), unless such instantiation is required.
> [...]

[P0859](https://wg21.link/P0859) which is a C++20 Defect Report against C++11 defines, that this also applies to `constexpr` functions.

---

During my investigation it turned out that MSVC, GCC and clang behave differently with regard to template instantiations and, in my opinion, all of them are not fully compliant to the standard.

The following bug reports have been created:

- MSVC: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/10604135

  - Based on MS STL: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/4417
  - Based on MSVC: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/10514504
- GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=114076
- clang: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/83409

Many thanks to everyone who took part in the discussion in the comments and bug reports! I will keep this answer updated whenever new information is available from these bug reports.

---

To understand what is going wrong, I would like to demonstrate the different behavior of the three compilers.

GitHub user [frederick-vs-ja](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/4417#issuecomment-1960976417) has reduced the problem in the MS STL Bug Report to a minimal example.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Holder {
    Holder() = default;
    constexpr ~Holder() { static_assert(sizeof(T) || true); }
};

struct Incomplete;

struct Class {
    Class();
    ~Class();

    Holder<Incomplete> v{};
};

int main() { [[maybe_unused]] Class v; }
```

I have extended this example with some variants and tested the compilers with them. Syntactically, there are 7 ways to call the default constructor of Holder:

- `Holder<Incomplete> a;` default-initialization
- `Holder<Incomplete> b{};` direct-list-initialization
- `Holder<Incomplete> c = {};` copy-list-initialization
- `Holder<Incomplete> d = Holder<Incomplete>();` copy-direct-initialization
- `Holder<Incomplete> e = {Holder<Incomplete>()};` copy-list-initialization
- `Holder<Incomplete> f = Holder<Incomplete>{};` copy-direct-initialization
- `Holder<Incomplete> g = {Holder<Incomplete>{}};` copy-list-initialization

Then we can change `Holder` in two ways. (Thanks to Github user [fsb4000](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/4417#issuecomment-1959604006) in the MS STL bug report!)

First we can remove the explicit constructor definition, so the compiler generates this constructor implicitly:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Holder {
    constexpr ~Holder() { static_assert(sizeof(T) || true); }
};
```

Second we can remove the constexpr from the destructor:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Holder {
    Holder() = default;
    ~Holder() { static_assert(sizeof(T) || true); }
};
```

A third relevant change can be applied to `B`. (Thanks to [Jiang An](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=114076#c1) in the GCC bug report!) We can make it a template, by giving it a default template argument:

```cpp
template <typename = void>
struct Class {
    Class();
    ~Class();

    Holder<Incomplete> v{};
};
```

So we have 8 code examples with 7 kinds of initialization. I created a table with what works with which compiler. I tested with MSVC 19.38, GCC 13.2 and clang 17.0.1. Each table cell links to the live code, where the trunk versions of the compilers are used additionally.

- Case 1: *Implicit `Holder` ctor*, *non-`constexpr` dtor*, *non-template `Class`*
- Case 2: Explicit `Holder` ctor, *non-`constexpr` dtor*, *non-template `Class`*
- Case 3: *Implicit `Holder` ctor*, `constexpr` dtor, *non-template `Class`*
- Case 4: Explicit `Holder` ctor, `constexpr` dtor, *non-template `Class`*
- Case 5: *Implicit `Holder` ctor*, *non-`constexpr` dtor*, template `Class`
- Case 6: Explicit `Holder` ctor, *non-`constexpr` dtor*, template `Class`
- Case 7: *Implicit `Holder` ctor*, `constexpr` dtor, template `Class`
- Case 8: Explicit `Holder` ctor, `constexpr` dtor, template `Class`

The order is: ✅/❌ MSVC ; ✅/❌ GCC ; ✅/❌ clang

|  | Case a | Case b | Case c | Case d | Case e | Case f | Case g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Case 1: | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/qY48zxTzG) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/Wxffo17os) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/WozTK8hWr) | [✅❌✅](https://godbolt.org/z/1cadT95Kf) | [✅❌✅](https://godbolt.org/z/nGP6YW79q) | [✅❌✅](https://godbolt.org/z/TKoT77cqG) | [✅❌✅](https://godbolt.org/z/1cj3x8cPW) |
| Case 2: | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/zMhsh5j8h) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/s47eWvG1v) | [✅❌✅](https://godbolt.org/z/zcrf7MWsG) | [✅❌✅](https://godbolt.org/z/cKboeqqqh) | [✅❌✅](https://godbolt.org/z/17Kn1Mx6b) | [✅❌✅](https://godbolt.org/z/688jqq9W7) | [✅❌✅](https://godbolt.org/z/sTMhYnc7Y) |
| Case 3: | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/8h4rK5M6e) | [❌✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/8jE9aEx47) | [❌✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/3ozv17bhY) | [❌❌❌](https://godbolt.org/z/qfseqbjE6) | [❌❌❌](https://godbolt.org/z/or1EcEjGb) | [❌❌❌](https://godbolt.org/z/8sh73dxbK) | [❌❌❌](https://godbolt.org/z/37Ghdz5G7) |
| Case 4: | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/8f34MeKsc) | [❌✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/5oeKTPvMx) | [❌❌✅](https://godbolt.org/z/PvWTxrxWf) | [❌❌❌](https://godbolt.org/z/hjjGeM5rY) | [❌❌❌](https://godbolt.org/z/oTo5vajx5) | [❌❌❌](https://godbolt.org/z/nq5GY78xM) | [❌❌❌](https://godbolt.org/z/Wq7Y41anW) |
| Case 5: | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/Tbedh7hea) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/MT8Goan3d) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/dj9h5nhx6) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/jP4hEas4P) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/4roT93oao) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/ddf9M85oo) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/MWGEfrhGP) |
| Case 6: | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/sjbzTqvYe) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/vGTvPfq8Y) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/v9zs6a9bf) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/b88Mdxvf6) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/9d54h8jh9) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/34G61zT1s) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/hT16d1aav) |
| Case 7: | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/odWz3qWvr) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/eoWYn6xzz) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/8nM6PfqEd) | [✅✅❌](https://godbolt.org/z/MEzs5c7hE) | [✅✅❌](https://godbolt.org/z/f4sardcvM) | [✅✅❌](https://godbolt.org/z/ore1M5dEM) | [✅✅❌](https://godbolt.org/z/obzGvvW3c) |
| Case 8: | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/1cvq6Ecvc) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/MKj58he9r) | [✅✅✅](https://godbolt.org/z/ajnobT6rs) | [✅✅❌](https://godbolt.org/z/hT7v4rbMd) | [✅✅❌](https://godbolt.org/z/jfWr4e37o) | [✅✅❌](https://godbolt.org/z/8eEGf3WP9) | [✅✅❌](https://godbolt.org/z/EYdsdv7EE) |

Cases d, e, f and g can apparently be considered as one case.